# Настройка Bios для запуска установки ОС с помощью PXE boot

Tags: linux, windows, bios, cluster, pxe

Задача такова: есть несколько машин для  сборки кластера, на главную машину установлена кластерная ОС, которая выступает в качестве сервера для PXE boot для оставльных машин в локальной сети по адресу 10.1.1.1
.  не получается правильно настроить биос American Megatrends для запуска установки ОС по локальной сети через  PXE boot

Comment: судя по опечатке "правально" - как раз всё получилось ). А если серьёзно - то что именно не получается? не запускается поиск PXE?  сервер не отвечает на запрос? подключение я надеюсь по проводу? а куда - в мать или во внешнюю сетевуху? точно у них есть поддержка PXE? приведи фото настроек биоса которые используются. и модель материнки/сетевой карты

Comment: Машины соединены по локальной сети, не получается запустить поиск PXE.  Кабель подключен к материнской плате.  Huanan x99 китайская материнка.